How to stop website registration redirection if user exits shopify
Have a website developed using shopify, in registration page when registered email is again submitted, show the error in the same page itself.
For me it is redirecting to login page instead of staying in the same page. have done many customization code to stop redirection but nothing works.
<div class="customer-page theme-default-margin">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 offset-lg-3 col-md-8 offset-md-2">
          <div class="login">
            <div class="login-form-container">
              <div class="login-text">
                <h2>{{ 'customer.register.title' | t }}</h2>
                {% if settings.register_sub_text != '' %}
                <p>{{ settings.register_sub_text }}</p>
                {% endif %}
              </div>
              <div class="register-form">
                {% form 'create_customer', return_to: routes.account_url %}
                {{ form.errors | default_errors }}
                <label for="FirstName" class="hidden-label">{{ 'customer.register.first_name' | t }}</label>
                <input type="text" name="customer[first_name]" id="FirstName" class="input-full" placeholder="{{ 'customer.register.first_name' | t }}" {% if form.first_name %}value="{{ form.first_name }}"{% endif %} autocapitalize="words" autofocus>
  
                <label for="LastName" class="hidden-label">{{ 'customer.register.last_name' | t }}</label>
                <input type="text" name="customer[last_name]" id="LastName" class="input-full" placeholder="{{ 'customer.register.last_name' | t }}" {% if form.last_name %}value="{{ form.last_name }}"{% endif %} autocapitalize="words">
  
                <label for="Email" class="hidden-label">{{ 'customer.register.email' | t }}</label>
                <input type="email" name="customer[email]" id="Email" class="input-full{% if form.errors contains 'email' %} error{% endif %}" placeholder="{{ 'customer.register.email' | t }}" {% if form.email %} value="{{ form.email }}"{% endif %} autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" >
  
                <label for="CreatePassword" class="hidden-label">{{ 'customer.register.password' | t }}</label>
                <input type="password" name="customer[password]" id="CreatePassword" class="input-full{% if form.errors contains 'password' %} error{% endif %}" placeholder="{{ 'customer.register.password' | t }}">
  
                <div class="form-action-button">
                  <button type="submit" class="theme-default-button">{{ 'customer.register.submit' | t }}</button>
                </div>
                {% if form.posted_successfully? %}
                  <p>Thanks for contacting us! We will get in touch with you shortly.</p>
                {% endif %}
                {% endform %}
                
                <div class="account-optional-action">
                    <a href="{{ shop.url }}">{{ 'customer.register.cancel' | t }}</a>
                </div>
  
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

google custom code & script to block the redirection

If redirection is happening it will be in php or javascript code, not in the html you've shown. Please provide a [mre] of your issue and clarify what you've already tried, then we can help you properly. See also [ask]. Thanks
